Is it normal for a ball valve housing to corrode shortly after installation?
In April, I had a contractor overhaul a portion of our water supply infrastructure by replacing the pressure tank and sediment filter connected to our well source. About four months later, I noticed that the ball valves installed on either side of the sediment filter show signs of corrosion. There were three ball valves of this kind installed in this project; two that isolate the sediment filter, and one normally closed bypass. The bypass does not show any corrosion, and neither do any of the other copper fittings and ball valves of different model installed at the same time.
(I do not have photographic evidence that these three valves looked identical at the time of installation -- the proposition that they were installed pre-corroded and their current condition has nothing to do with the installation and current application is a fair argument.)

I am relatively new to dealing with plumbing; the only time I've seen this kind of corrosion before is on a hydronic heating system using an antifreeze (which causes corrosion if not properly maintained). My interpretation of what I'm seeing here is that the ball valves are experiencing corrosion as a result of being open and having water flow through them, but I am suspicious that this is to be expected.
Our well water has a reasonable level of iron, and we do soften it at about four grains, as well as using a FlowTech ultrasonic descaler. My best guess as to the root  cause is that the minerals in our water are interacting with the brass in the valves, but I wouldn't know if this is expected to happen so soon or is evidence of an installation or manufacturing defect. These just stand  out because none of the other fittings installed at the same time are showing this level of corrosion so quickly.
From what I can tell based on the markings on the handles, these valves are Giacomini R850V LF. I can't find any official specs for these valves besides their listings in NSF, though the R850V datasheet can be found listing those as valves "suitable for dangerous gas and liquid hydrocarbons".
Why are these valves and only these valves corroding so quickly?

There's nothing at all unusual about valves made from cheap brass alloys to be showing significant corrosion within days, if exposed to moisture (rain, condensation, etc.)


My interpretation of what I'm seeing here is that the ball valves are experiencing corrosion as a result of being open and having water flow through them

This was my first thought as well. Albeit, I offer a slightly different take; it's probably residue.
If cold water is passing through those valves then they could be sweating from the outside and what you are seeing is leftover residue from the humidity in your air. Similar to how you get some salt if you boil away ocean water.
If you clean up the valves with some CLR then do they look new again?
Actual corrosion affects metal integrity so once you wash it with CLR then you could reveal signs of failure as opposed to merely residue.

I agree. That is not corrosion, but a residue and is totally inconsequential.  Wipe it off if it bothers you.
